# Spring Swagger-ui integration

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

Needless to say I know there are a ton of questions about this same subject but I've been stuck trying to fix this for 2 days now and most of what I've read is outdated.

So yeah.. this is what I have right now:

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.4.0'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.4.0'
}
```

Main class:

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeedServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public Docket swaggerSettings() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/");
}
```

When I visit: http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs, I get the json documentation just fine. Also when I download swagger-ui from github, set the source to the link above and run it on desktop, it also works fine. What doesn't work is putting these 2 things together (getting it to work at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html).

There are many tutorials such as these, where they claim the stuff above will make swagger-ui work:

http://kubecloud.io/guide-using-swagger-for-documenting-your-spring-boot-rest-api/

http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

And a ton of other tutorials where they instruct you to add dist folder from swagger-ui git to your project.

Also mapping like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("**/swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/"); 
    registry.addResourceHandler("**/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }
}
```

Fails as well, throwing Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; exception.

After trying some tutorials from youtube, the ones linked above and many others, all I've seen is "page not found". If anyone could explain what I'm missing I would be very grateful.

TL:DR How do I get swagger-ui.html to work?

EDIT: found the **solution**.

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, the problem is that if you have a request mapping that takes in a parameter `@RequestMapping("/{param}")`, dispatcherServlet no longer maps /** to ResourceHttpRequestHandler. The code below fixes that issue.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    @Override public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Comment: The swagger-ui you must use is the one provided by springfox and that uses webjar, so no html or css files to install manually in your webapp.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Was stuck in the same problem.

Comment: Better you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Answer (score 0):

That's what we use as setup. A class for its own annotated with @Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error")))
      .build()
      .apiInfo(apiInfo());
  }
  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfo(
      "APP NAME",
      "APP DESCRIPTION",
      "1.0",
      null,
      new Contact("Firstname Lastname", null, "firstname.lastname@somewhere.net"),
    null,
    null);
```

}
    }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this also but there's no endpoint for the ui.

Comment: At which address are you looking? you seem to add v2 there, our swagger gui is located at host:8050/swagger-ui.html , where 8050 is the port that is exposed.

Comment: I'm looking at /swagger-ui.html and v2/swagger-ui.html but I see all the endpoints in console (for example I see v2/api-docs just fine) and there's no endpoint for the ui.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spi</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Convert the above dependency to gradle.
Version i used is 2.3.1

```
package XXXX;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

}
```

We enabled the Swagger Config as stated above.

You can add Docket bean for custom headers:

```
@Bean
  public Docket docket() {

 Parameter parameterAuthorization =
        new ParameterBuilder().name("Authorization").description("Authentication of the API User")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(true).build();

    Parameter parameterClientUserId =
        new ParameterBuilder().name("user_id").description("Client user identifier")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(true).build();

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
        .globalOperationParameters(Lists.newArrayList(parameterClientUserId, parameterAuthorization));
  }
```

And finally **import the Swagger config in Main Application Class** on Spring boot

@Import({SwaggerConfiguration.class})

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this but still got no endpoint for the ui.